# Jenkins Extension Point for Job API

Tags: java, api, plugins, jenkins

Is there a Extension Point for the Job REST API?

I want to add some information when http://server/jenkins/job/job_name/job_number/api/json is called.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a lot of research and tries, I've found the answer.

To expose additional data in the Job/Build REST API, the TransientActionFactory (http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/TransientActionFactory.html) needs to be extended using the AbstractBuild (http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html) as it type.

You'll have something like this:

```
import hudson.Extension;
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild;
import hudson.model.Action;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import jenkins.model.TransientActionFactory;


@Extension
public class MyTransientActionFactory extends TransientActionFactory<AbstractBuild> {
    @Override
    public Class<AbstractBuild> type() {
        return AbstractBuild.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends Action> createFor(AbstractBuild target) {
        return Collections.singleton(new MyAction(target));
    }
}
```

That will add MyAction to the AbstractBuild actions list which is shown in the REST API.

Comment: Could you please share the code for MyAction as well.. I can't get this working..